# Fortran: best intent () for local variables

Tags: fortran

What is the best intent () to use with variables that are local to a subroutine?  These are neither passed into or out of the subroutine but may be modified during execution of the subroutine.  What about local named constants (parameters)?

Comment: No intent declaration. Only use intent for in or out variables.

Comment: Local variables that are constants that will never be altered can be declared with the `parameter` attribute.  That is good programming practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The INTENT attribute can only be applied to dummy arguments.

Source that attempts to apply the INTENT attribute to something that is not a dummy argument, such as a local variable or a named constant, will result in a syntax error from a Fortran compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `intent()` is just for variables that are either coming into the subroutine or coming out of it not for local variables. if you use the `intent()` for local variables, the compiler produces error.

`intent()` is used for dummy variables.